# Scrollbar overlaps content of fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div (a shopping cart list) on the right side. If there are too many items, a scroll bar appears. The problem is, it partially covers the fixed div. How can I make the div push left when the scroll bar appears so it won't be covered?

[image: Scollbar Problem]

My CSS:

```
/* sidebar-right */
#sidebar-wrapper-right {
    margin-left: -250px;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav-right li {
    line-height: 40px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav-right li a {
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav-right li a .item-count {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.sidebar-nav-right li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav-right > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav-right > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #000;
}

.sidebar-nav-right > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

#sidebar-wrapper-right .sidebar-nav-right .sidebar-right-trash {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -10px;
    top: 12px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper-right .sidebar-nav-right .sidebar-right-trash:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper-right">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav-right">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">[Shopping Cart]</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">5</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">10</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">10</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">10</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">10</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">10</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash sidebar-right-trash pull-left"></a>
            <a href="market/#">[X] <span class="badge pull-right item-count">10</span></a>
        </li>
        <hr class="sidebar-seperator">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the scrollbar to push the content over?

Comment: Yea, the content should be pushed to the left so the scrollbar does not overlap it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `overflow-y:auto;` from the div element and add `overflow-y:auto; height:100%` to ul element.
http://jsfiddle.net/gLdCg/

Answer (score 0):

add an fix height to the sidebar

```
#sidebar-wrapper-right {
    margin-left: -250px;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px; /*or max-height:300px;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Put the list into a small, nearly invisible table, and put  some cell padding into the side. That'll keep the list off the side of the screen. OR you can very specifically place the table into a postion that wont be affected using:

```
//PUT the and right pixels in the number that the scroll bar is generally.
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; right:(NUMBER OF PIXELS AWAY FROM THE RIGHT)px>
```

I personally would use the absolute placement, but that's just me.

Happy to help!